# What is ur suggestion for this Java class designe

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have some concussion to make proper design for the following interface and class. The requirement is the following:-

```
public interface Entity {
    // Returns entity name
    String getName();
    // Returns a unique identifier
    String getID();
    // Returns the sub-entities of this entity
    Set<Entity> getSubEntities();
    // Returns a set of key-value data belonging to this entity
    Map<String,String> getData();
}

public class SubEntity implements Entity {

private String ID;
private String name;
private int price;
private Set<Entity> sbuEntities;

public SubEntity(){
    ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

public SubEntity(String name, int price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.ID = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void addSubEntity(Entity entity){
    if(sbuEntities == null){
        sbuEntities = new HashSet<>();
    }
    sbuEntities.add(entity);
};

public Set<Entity> getSubEntities(){
    return sbuEntities;
}

public Map<String, String> getData() {
    if(sbuEntities == null){
        sbuEntities = new HashSet<>();
    }
    return sbuEntities.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getID,
                    Object::toString));
}

public String toString() {
    return "SubEntity{" +
            "id='" + ID + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", price=" + price +
            '}';
}
}
```

There could be many types of SubEnitity that implement this interface. Also, every SubEnitity should have a Set as Set subentities or Set sbuEntities. I have confusion about the Set. Should I keep inside the SubEntity or outside. I would like to know your opinion with possible pros an cons.

Comment: I think the question is too board and we have no knowledge on `Entity` under your problem domain.

Comment: I implemented one possible SubEntity. My confusion is about the  Set<Entity> sbuEntities; Should it be Set<SubEntity> sbuEntities or Set<Entity> sbuEntities. So should I keep inside the SubEntity or outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In depends a bit on your use-case.**
Let us take an example to break this down.

Let's say an Entity is a food-product. This could be a lot of things: a cookie, a jar of milk, a bottle of wine.

Let's say you want a SubEntity of that food-product (your SubEntity class) to group together all Cookies. So now we have:

- Entity ( = Food)
- SubEntity ( = Cookie)

Inside your SubEntity you have a Set of food-"things" that have a relation with your SubEntity.

For me, it would be logical that your Set would only exist out of stuff that IS or HAS a Cookie. So your set could contain "a chocolate chip cookie", a "peanut butter cookie".
I don't think it makes sense that your Cookie class would have "a jar of milk" or "a bottle of wine".
Thus: `Set<SubEntity>`

**On the other hand:**

If you want your Cookie class (SubEntity) to have a set of things that pair well with cookies (e.g. something to drink with it), you could have "lemonade" or "coffee". In that case, it would make sense to do `Set<Entity>`.